# Exception in SynchronizationContext when calling OperationFuture outside of callstack

Tags: java, google-cloud-sdk, cloud-document-ai

I am using Google's DocumentAI SDK but this error stems from the gRPC SDK it seems. I am calling an asynchronous operation in DocumentAI which returns an `OperationFuture`. When I call the method `OperationFuture.get()` within the callstack frame where the future is created, the code properly blocks until the future completes and continues normally. If however the method that creates the future returns and I call the `OperationFuture.get()` outside of its creation frame I always get an exception with the following stacktrace

```
io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$2 uncaughtException
SEVERE: [Channel<1>: (us-documentai.googleapis.com:443)] Uncaught exception in the SynchronizationContext. Panic!
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@60d4b478 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@1e3a60f5[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:326)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel$PendingCall.reprocess(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1089)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel.updateConfigSelector(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1022)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener$1NamesResolved.run(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1729)
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.drain(SynchronizationContext.java:95)
    at io.grpc.SynchronizationContext.execute(SynchronizationContext.java:127)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$NameResolverListener.onResult(ManagedChannelImpl.java:1815)
    at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Sample **pseudo**code

```
public class Engine {
    public void startAsync() {
      ...
      OperationFuture future = googleClient.doAsyncRequest();
      // calling future.get(); here works fine
      this.operationFuture = future;
      ...
    }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    Engine eng = new Engine();
    eng.startAsync();
    eng.operationFuture.get(); // this doesn't work
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: The pseudo code is way too generic and not detailed enough to investigate the error, can you shared more or an article from where you are trying to replicate?

Comment: I have found the problem, will be posting a solution soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the source of the problem. The reason the operation works within the stack frame but not outside is because the `googleClient` object that creates and manages this `operationFuture` has its own `ExecutorService` which handles the `operationFuture` lifecycle. Once we return from the `startAsync()` method, the `googleClient` object goes out of scope and is freed which also frees all threads that were associated with it and corrupting the `operationFuture` object.

In order to solve this problem the `googleClient` object must be kept alive in memory along with the `operationFuture`. For example for DocumentAI:

```
public void startAsync() {
    ...
    this.googleClient = DocumentProcessorServiceClient.create(docAISettings);
    this.operationFuture = this.googleClient.doAsyncRequest();
    return;
}
```

Calling the `operationFuture.get()` method from out side now works properly as long as both the future and the client object have not gone out of scope.

I have tried to provide a custom thread pool to the `googleClient` object and let it be garbage collected (i.e. the `googleClient` object dies but the thread running the `operationFuture` doesn't) but it doesn't seem to work, not sure why.

Comment: Could this be because operationFuture has current running operations? have you tried to cancel any queued operations? Perhaps your GC needs some fine tunning? Or maybe consider using a different GC?

Comment: You should open a thread for your GC issue.